# min max problem with eigenvalues for A and A*A

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is invertible. Say $λ_m, λ_M$ are the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A$. And $β_m$,$β_M$ be the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A^*A$. Show that $0<β_m ≤|λ_m|^2 ≤|λ_M|^2 ≤β_M$.

Here is what I have now:
maximize $\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle = \langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\\$
$ =\langle λx,λx\rangle = arg(λ)\langle λx,x\rangle = arg(λ)Max\langle Ax,x\rangle = arg(λ_M)λ_M= β_M\\$.
If $λ_M = a+bi$, then $β_M = a^2 + b^2$. But isn't that the same case for $|λ_M|^2$? How to show $β_m ≤|λ_m|^2$ and $|λ_M|^2 ≤β_M$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on the right track.

**Hint**:

For a set $S \subset \mathbb R$ and some arbitrary $x^*\in S$, it is obvious that
$$\min_{x\in S} x \leq x^* \leq \max_{x\in S} x.$$

Now what is a set with $\beta_m$ as its $\min$ and $\beta_M$ as its $\max$?
Once you identify that set, all that remains is to prove that $|\lambda_m|^2$ and $|\lambda_M|^2$ belong to that set (which you have already done).

Comment: I think I got it! thank you